# Independence of joint probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose there are 3 random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ such that $X$ is independent of both $Y$ and $Z$. This means that

$P(X|Z) = P(X|Y) = P(X)$.

Is it then the case that $X$ is independent of the joint probability distribution $P(Y, Z)$ such that $P(X | Y,Z) = P(X)$?

My intuition says that this should be true but I am not sure how to go about proving it to myself.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how is that intuitive. I think one can intuitively see that the statement cannot be true in general. Informally speaking the assumptions are like if you know $Y$ you still don't know $X$. If you know $Z$ you still don't know $X$. What about if you know both $Y$ and $Z$? Think about something like the volume for instance. If you know the mass you don't know the volume. If you know the density you don't know the volume either. BUT if you know both mass and density then you know the volume. Those kind of things help you to construct a counterexample.

Comment: And one counterexample is given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually (perhaps surprisingly) false. To see it, let Y and Z be iid Bernoulli(1/2), and X = Y XOR Z. (In more English; Y is 1 with probability (w.p.) 1/2, and 0 w.p. 1/2, and the same for Z. Now, if Y and Z are the same, X is 0, and if they are different, X is 1).

Now, you can check that X is independent from Y and Z by definition (just do it case-by-case), but it is certainly not independent from Y and Z when they are given together!